# How to use an auto incremented primary key as a foreign key as well?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, auto-increment, database-relations

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have 2 tables...

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `related_ids` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `related_ids` (`related_ids`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And then a constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `parent` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `child` (`parent_id`);
```

As you can see the table parent has an auto-incremented primary key "id", which is also being used as a foreign key for the child table.

Now I want to insert a record in the parent table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO parent SET DATA="abc";
```

And it fails with error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails
>   (`myschema`.`parent`, CONSTRAINT
>   `parent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
>   REFERENCES `child` (`parent_id`))

I understand that it fails because it doesn't find a referred record in the child table. If I start by creating a record in the child table, set it's parent_id to 1, then reset the auto-increment counter of the parent table (so that the next insert will have id = 1), it works! But that's not a solution.

I don't see the utility of the insert blocking if there is no related row in the child table...

I'm just trying to do a one-to-many relationship...

(I know I can use JOIN, but I'm trying to use table relations, for data integrity and also as metadata for PHP)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have the referencing and referenced tables in reverse. You may want to do:

```
ALTER TABLE `child ` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`);
```

You can also define the foreign key in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `related_ids` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `related_ids` (`related_ids`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Test case:

```
INSERT INTO parent (`data`) VALUES ('test data 1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO parent (`data`) VALUES ('test data 2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO child (`parent_id`, `related_ids`) VALUES (1, 100);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO child (`parent_id`, `related_ids`) VALUES (2, 100);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

INSERT INTO child (`parent_id`, `related_ids`) VALUES (3, 100);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: 
  a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: +1: I realized I misread the question when I read your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just realized that myself!

Comment: I already defined identity in SQL server 2012 but i am trying to pass some value to db. So at that place( auto-incremented) what do I need to pass??

Comment: Ok, got that. But how could this be solved when creating tables with a one-to-one relationship, and you'd like to use a `ON DELETE CASCADE` so that when the *child* is deleted, the parent is deleted too? Or even both ways (if the child is deleted, the parent is deleted; if the parent is deleted, the child is deleted). I'm guessing it's not possible with foreign key constraints, and using them with a one-to-one table relationship just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Uh... I think I got it backwards.
It seems that I need to add the foreign key to the child table, like that:

```
ALTER TABLE `child` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`);
```

I'm having a hard time dealing with MySQL terminology. Can you blame me?

Comment: I'm glad you realized what the problem is. If you think about it, it's not that difficult to understand. A foreign key is a **constraint**. And you'll be adding the constraint on the `child` table, because the `parent` field of the `child` table will be constrained into accepting a value only if that value exists in the `id` column of the `parent` table.