# Matching auto_increment primary keys between tables on insertion

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, sql-insert

I have two tables:

```
table1- id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
```

id is an auto_increment.

```
table2- id, col1, col2, col3
```

In this, id is also Auto_increment and primary key on (col1,col2,col3).

My HTML form has some inputs; upon submit button click, I insert some inputs into `table1` and the remaining inputs into `table2`. But the ids of these do not match. How can I ensure that the id of each newly inserted record is the same between the tables?

Comment: Nope! But when I am inserting this record.It is not on diffrent time..query fire line by line..so.

Comment: What do you mean by "not on different time"? If you have a matching reference in all tables, say for userA, with username "BOB", you insert all his data with colum `username = BOB`, then to get all userA data, select on all tables where `username = BOB`. (Usernames, address etc are just examples. I'm not writing your code for you, just showing you the way)

Comment: Ok so I can check near primary set that I have used right.

Comment: I completely rewrote your title and summary paragraph to explain your apparent problem. I also added some useful tags to increase visibility and edited the intro some to clarify the problem somewhat.

Comment: Try foreign key instead - check solutions there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544322/how-to-use-an-auto-incremented-primary-key-as-a-foreign-key-as-well

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, and a sample query that attempts to do your task.